# mlflow on Windows10 and desktop.ini

Tags: pytorch, mlflow

it's the first time for me to leave a question here.
I'm currently using PyTorch on my research and trying to organize results with MLFlow.
I know that many problems when using MLflow on Windows10 but since there are no options for this... I'm trying to get used to it.
Errors that I encounter here are "Metrics 'desktop.ini' is malformed ...'
This error is nagging me when -

1. Using `mlflow ui` to see experiment results from the past [mlflow ui error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k070v.png)
2. When trying to use `mlflow.pytorch.log_model(model, ...)` [pytorch.log_model error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3mUX.png)

These two are the main concerns for me. My question here is

1. Is there other result organizing tools that I can use except tensorboard?
2. Is there any method that can save `model.pth` from pytorch to mlflow? + if it's impossible, are there  any other formats that we use to save the configuration (such as YAML, other hierarchical languages like XML..)

Thank you